# Push a zip file to azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I checked the azure devops rest api documentation, couldn't found how to push a zip file using azure devops rest api. Please help with some sample code.

Comment: push zip file to where? to a work item? to azure artifacts?

Comment: Upload Zip file To azure repo.

Comment: to azure git repo?

Comment: Yes to azure git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#update-a-file).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=6.0
```

The request body is as same as adding a binary file. Here is the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-a-binary-file).

You need to convert your zip file to binary, then push it.

Comment: While downloading Or pulling the same file how to implement.